# Algorithmic Paradigm of the Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, increment, insertion-sort, paradigms

Recently I started studying sorting algorithms again and I was wondering which algorithmic paradigm category would better describe the `insertion sort`. I have researched the web to link the insertion sort to a specific paradigm, however I could not find a certain answer. For other sorting algorithms like the `quicksort` or `mergesort` the answer is very evident, i.e. the `Divide and Conquer` paradigm. The only data I was able to find for the insertion sort states that it has an "[incremental approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)". However I couldn't find a specific paradigm regarding the incremental approach. I would much appreciate if anyone is able to clear the definition of these, and explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of "incremental approach" is to enable the user to visualise intermediate results until a desired final result is achieved.

How this relates to insertion sort is that, in insertion sort, say we are planning to sort array till "j" position, when we reach at this particular position, insertion sort algorithm will have sorted the sub-array A[1…j - 1], and then we insert the single element A[ j] into its proper place, yielding the sorted sub-array A[1…j].

Comment: Ok, I now see how the incremental approach works. Having said that, can we call the "incremental approach" an algorithmic paradigm which includes the insertion sort? Or the incremental approach can be an attribute of many paradigms? If incremental approach is not a paradigm, which paradigm type the insertion sort falls under (ex: backtracking, dynamic, BB, etc.)?